# get request data in Umbraco 7.2

Tags: c#, asp.net, umbraco7

I have a form created with Umbraco forms and in the submit I have redirect to other page with other template, how I can get the request data in the second page?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to add a new Workflow to the form to handle the submitted data?

Really Umbraco Forms creates an entity for each submission, which is different from the HTTP POST Form action as it were, there are [some videos on Umbraco.tv](http://umbraco.tv/videos/umbraco-v7/implementor/extending/umbraco-forms/http://umbraco.tv/videos/umbraco-v7/implementor/extending/umbraco-forms/) that go into more detail.  Hope this helps.